# Dollar sign not allowed in env-cmd

Tags: reactjs, cryptlib, env-cmd

I would like to ask if what's wrong with the dollar sign within the environment variable? I tried to do everything to fix the problem I've encountered using env-cmd package from npm with react

Sample

```
.env.development

REACT_SECRET_CODE=$B&FG%@(*4Fgawq@)
```

After a few hours of debugging then until I've noticed that it removes the ***$*** sign from the example env variable ***REACT_SECRET_CODE*** then the variable shown in the console log is `&FG%@(*4Fgawq@)` instead of `$B&FG%@(*4Fgawq@)`

Comment: Just an idea, could you try escaping the $, perhaps like so: "\$B&..", it appears to me the interpreter is trying to substitute the variable B in the expression which is undefined hence empty.

Comment: Ok sir I'll try it :)

Comment: Thanks sir it works :)

Comment: Cool, great to hear :). I wrote an official answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply escaping the dollar sign will solve the issue.

The reason this has to be done is because otherwise, for `$B`, `env-cmd` will try to perform **variable substitution** on the variable `B`, which is empty and will resolve to an empty string.